# mstest deployment - deploy to TestResults directory

Tags: deployment, resharper, mstest

I am using mstest and I need to copyfiles out of the directory of the "Out" directory and rename "Out" directory.

The current structure is:

```
TestResults/
  Out/
    Resources/
      resource.txt
    dll and pdb
```

I need the structure to be -

```
TestResults/
  Resources/
   resource.txt
  bin/
   dll and pdb
```

How can I do this in MSTest?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in your configuration file. Check out this page:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee256991.aspx